# Kubeflow being slow when I am closing the tab

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow

I am facing this weird issue with Kubeflow, say I have put some job on 1M Data (Audio files) and closed the tab on edge browser. After 1 day when I open the directory where the data should be generated I am seeing only 10K files generated. More interestingly if I count the files just after 1 minute of, then it is showing me around 15k files.

So my doubt is how come only 10k files can be generated in 12 hours and 5k is generated within 1 minute. Does this have anything to do with me closing the tab in my browser (which shouldn't be so and a dump question to ask), if not then what?